# Discord, is there a way to mass delete all deletable roles?

Tags: discord.js

As I said in the title, I want to try deleting all deletable roles, only deletable ones
I tried making a code it looks like this

```
message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => role.deletable && role.delete())
```

Unfortunately, it does not print any errors, and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.each(role => {
  if (role.editable && role.name !== "@everyone") {
     // you can do .catch(err => undefined) too 
     role.delete().catch(err => console.log(role.name));
  }
});
```

Comment: Looked at docs and `role.deletable` is not a property so I'm guessing that's why, another solution is to just delete it and catch any errors. Edited my answer.

Comment: Also `.editable` is a property so you can check that instead if you like.

Comment: Tho it prints an error
```DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions```

Comment: The ways i gave you shouldn't print an error but anyways I tried it out myself and I think the issue is the `@everyone` role, I have edited the code to code that I have tested and works. This obviously still needs perms to delete certain roles, so if it's not deleting ones you want, make sure it has delete role option AND it's above the roles you want to delete

Comment: It's working just perfectly, thanks mate for helping me, Appreciate your help <3

Comment: No problem, make sure to accept the answer incase someone else stumbles upons this post.